# How can I tell if my gold C-3PO minifigure is legit?

Tags: minifigures, star-wars

I just bought a used gold C-3PO (not the 14k version, but the 10,000-made version). There are some places under the arms and on the right foot where there is no gold paint. I *think* that they are all like this, but I'm not sure. I'm looking for someone to verify that I didn't just get taken to the cleaners. I can still open an eBay case if I need to.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that sounds like the genuine article - LEGO was unable to chrome each part separately, so there are bare spots where you describe. Only the customs will have been made up of individually chromed parts.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I have an original chrome gold CP30 and mine also has those bare spots. Like mentioned earlier, LEGO painted these units as a whole and not separately... so that's what's essentially makes them legit, and the bare spots are all the same on the originals. I have done research on it after I realized that's what I had was the worth a pretty penny haha

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry my friend, those "unchromed" spots are because of the regular use of that minifigure.